# Dynamically convert an instance array with multiple values

Tags: c#

Currently using a Scores class (code displaying the variables below) do, surprisingly, store the Users scores. The scores are currently held in a pre-defined (size) array due to vectors not existing in C#. I have researched and have found that there are two data structures (maybe more that I have not found but most likely irrelevant) for converting a static array to a dynamic set.

Linked lists and Array Lists.

From the research Linked Lists seem to be the preference of the majority.

```
public class Score
    {
        private int _ScoreId;
        public int ScoreId
        {
            get { return _ScoreId; }
            set
            {
                _ScoreId = value;
            }
        }
        private string _ScoreUsername;
        public string ScoreUsername
        {
            get { return _ScoreUsername; }
            set
            {
                if (value.Length >= 5 || value.Length <= 10)
                {
                    _ScoreUsername = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("The Username must be between 5 - 10 Characters");
                }
            }
        }
        private int _Turns;
        public int ScoreTurns
        {
            get { return _Turns; }
            set
            {
                if (_Turns >= 0)
                {
                    _Turns = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Invalid Turns Entry - Must have completed 1 turn");
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Current instance array initialization:

```
Score[] Scores = new Score[10];
```

The code where the Scores class is being used

```
 private void InsertScores(int scoreId, int scoreValue, string Username)
    {

            //Connection
            Connection();
            //Declare Object
            for (int Id = 0; Id < Scores.Length; Id++)
            {
                Scores[Id] = new Score();
            }

                //Select All rows and populate object instance
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM gameScores Order By scoreValue ASC", Con);
                int Element = 0;
                //data reader
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Scores[Element].ScoreId = Convert.ToInt32(rdr[0].ToString());
                    Scores[Element].ScoreTurns = Convert.ToInt32(rdr[1].ToString());
                    Scores[Element].ScoreUsername = rdr[2].ToString();
                    Element++;
                }
                rdr.Close();

            //int ScoreId = 9;
            if (scoreValue < Scores[9].ScoreTurns)
            {
                SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("UPDATE gameScores SET scoreValue = @scoreValue, username = @Username WHERE scoreid = @ScoreId;", Con);
                sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scoreValue", scoreValue);
                sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username);
                sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ScoreId", Scores[9].ScoreId);
                //Insert
                sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You sadly have not made the High Scores Leaderboard");
            }


    }
```

Has anyone converted a static array into a linked list when using an instance array? if so what steps did you take, have not seen much online documenting using linked lists for object arrays

Comment: Why not just use `List<T>`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `List<T>`. It is a great way to store arrays of objects.

Declaration :

```
List<Score> Scores = new List<Score>();
```

Usage :

```
private void InsertScores(int scoreId, int scoreValue, string Username)
    {

            //Connection
            Connection();

                //Select All rows and populate object instance
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM gameScores Order By scoreValue ASC", Con);
                //data reader
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Score score = new Score(); //Create object to store the data
                    score.ScoreId = Convert.ToInt32(rdr[0].ToString());
                    score.ScoreTurns = Convert.ToInt32(rdr[1].ToString());
                    score.ScoreUsername = rdr[2].ToString();
                    Scores.Add(score); //Add the object to the array
                }
                rdr.Close();

            //int ScoreId = 9;
            if (scoreValue < Scores[9].ScoreTurns)
            {
                SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("UPDATE gameScores SET scoreValue = @scoreValue, username = @Username WHERE scoreid = @ScoreId;", Con);
                sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scoreValue", scoreValue);
                sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username);
                sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ScoreId", Scores[9].ScoreId);
                //Insert
                sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You sadly have not made the High Scores Leaderboard");
            }


    }
```

Comment: To access the elements from a list storing an array of objects is the syntax similar? As in all the list is still accessible via Scores[number]? The current solution provided will overwrite each value while it continues to read

Comment: You can use `[]` to access an element in a `List<T>`

Comment: @HARVmackie Yes you can access the objects in the list just like you would in an array `Scores[9].ScoreTurns`.

Comment: @HARVmackie Why do you say the values are overwritten?